# NaN by Creating the power of Matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

Let's assume we have following matrix and want to build the power of 1.5 that is b^1.5 :

```
b <- matrix(c(1,2,4,4,-0.6,56), ncol=1)
b^1.5

           [,1]
[1,]   1.000000
[2,]   2.828427
[3,]   8.000000
[4,]   8.000000
[5,]        NaN
[6,] 419.065627
```

but

```
-0.6^1.5
[1] -0.464758
```

Is anyone aware of solution of this kind a problem?

Comment: Perhaps the underlying code tries to do a square root first, which fails on negative values. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=square+root+of+0.6+to+the+power+of+3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-0.6^1.5` is not the same as `(-0.6)^1.5`.

From `help("^")`:

> Users are sometimes surprised by the value returned, for example why
>   (-8)^(1/3) is NaN. For double inputs, R makes use of IEC 60559
>   arithmetic on all platforms, together with the C system function pow
>   for the ^ operator. The relevant standards define the result in many
>   corner cases. In particular, the result in the example above is
>   mandated by the C99 standard. On many Unix-alike systems the command
>   man pow gives details of the values in a large number of corner cases.

What do you want the result to be?

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the order of evaluation in R.

`-0.6^1.5` is really `0.6^1.5` times `-1`.  The exponent is evaluated before the negative.

When you put the `-0.6` into the matrix, the negative is applied to `0.6` when `b` is created.  That means that when you take the exponent, you are really doing this:

```
(-0.6)^1.5
# NaN
```